# How to fix my bootstrap and images path so it will activated with laravel?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, path

so i use bootstrap template in my public folder (laravel). When i open my views, the bootstrap layout and images are not activated. I think it is because the path is not right. Here is my code. I don't want to use .blade. Is there any solution to make the path right ? Thank You

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Aurora XXI Batch</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Worthy a Bootstrap-based, Responsive HTML5 Template">
    <meta name="author" content="htmlcoder.me">

    <!-- Mobile Meta -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/ico/favicon.ico"/>

    <!-- Web Fonts -->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,700italic,400,700,300&amp;subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:700,400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Font Awesome CSS -->
    <link href="fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Plugins -->
    <link href="css/animations.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Worthy core CSS file -->
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom css --> 
    <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this if you're using blade template

```
<link href="{{ asset('bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Is the `asset()` helper still around in L5.1? I couldn't find it in the docs or in the `helpers.php` file, but that doesn't mean it's not there of course. Either way, a more OO alternative to this would be to use the UrlGenerator's `asset` method: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php#L192

Comment: Ahh yes, it's in the `Foundation/helpers.php` file, not `Support/helpers.php` file.

Comment: but i dont want using blade template

Comment: You can still use PHP's `<?php echo asset('bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css'); ?>` instead of Blade.